# Run python code without installing python in highly restricted environment

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tomcat

I would like to run python scripts in a very restricted environment (banking).
I can't install anything.

I want to write webapps using python scripts that have to run on tomcat without installing python on the machine.
Java is installed.

Is that possible?

I am allowed to copy files over but no installations.

Comment: You can convert python scripts to executable using [cx-freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) (with mixed results in my experience). If you have java you could make the python scripts [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) compatible and run them on the JVM -- further than that I'm not sure this question is really on topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

py2exe should handle situations such as this. Directly from the tutorial site it says:

"py2exe turns Python programs into packages that can be run on other Windows computers without needing to install Python on those computers."

Source: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial